ER Studio - Can't connect to Oracle DB - oci.dll or ociw32.dll exists
I'm trying to connect to Oracle DB from idera ER Studio Data Architect 19.3.2. I have oracle DB client 64-bit and ER Studio Data Architect 19.3.2 64-bit installed in my local machine. I'm trying to reverse engineer a data model from the database which has all the tables/constraints created. However the problem is embarcadero is not letting me to connect to the oracle db and error message is as below.
What's going wrong here?
error:

can not load OCI, please verify that oci.dll or ociw32.dll exists in your path. Please make sure your version of OCI is 7.3.4 or greater.


Do you know which driver is used by Embarcadero ER studio? Are you sure it is 64 bit?

sorry its idera ER Studio Data Architect 19.3.2 but yes 64 bit.  (ERStudio_Data_Architect_19.3.2_Windows_Client_64bit)

The error message looks like a typical error from ancient Microsoft driver, e.g. Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle. Maybe check with Process Monitor which driver is actually used.
